# Show that if the matrix A has the form $\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ b& -a\end{pmatrix}$, so $ a^2+b^2= 1 $

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I need to prove that if matrix A has the form $\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ -b& a\end{pmatrix}$, or    $\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ b& -a\end{pmatrix}$

so $ a^2+b^2= 1 $

I picked a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a &b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}$, and I proved for this one.Then I changed $c = b$ and $d = -a$, but I'm not sure if this is correct. I'm not getting the correct answer, I didn't prove it.

Comment: What is the question???????????????

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}.$ Then we have: $A$ is orthogonal if $AA^T=I$. Hence

$$AA^T=I \iff a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1, ac+bd=0.$$